# Using splice() to remove items that matches condition from array

Tags: json, vue.js

Im trying to via a for-loop remove all the items that matches a condition in the state array. But it seems to only be removing the last items in the array and not the ones that matches. Am I using the .splice() incorrectly? Thanks in advance. Code is:

```
rmTravel() {
           for(var i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++){
               if(this.cards[i].sg_categories.includes("travel")){
                   this.cards.splice(i, 1);
                   console.log('Removed following card:', this.cards[i].slug)
               }
           }
           console.log('Cards in cards state: ', this.cards)
       }
```

Comment: **1.** If the `splice()` is supposed to remove an item from the array, then isn't your `console.log()` call too late? Shouldn't you print the item _before_ you delete it? **2.** When you remove an item from the array, don't the following items get shifted by one position towards the beginning of the array? If so, you should probably decrement `i` after deletion to process the item shifted into the position of the deleted item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a classic problem; you're iterating forward and shrinking the array at the same time so you're going to end up skipping over records.

I suggest using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead

```js
this.cards = this.cards.filter(({ sg_categories }) => 
    !sg_categories.includes('travel'))
```

This will reduce the array to entries who's `sg_categories` property does not include *"travel"*.

Comment: Splendid. This is what I was looking for. Thank you.